# Camel not able to call a rest service

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am trying to call REST services from my camel application in Jboss FUSE. Rest services are deployed in quarkus [localhost:9090].

Services are accessible when I try from browser or soapui but getting exception in camel.

Camel Application code :

```xml
    <setBody>
        <constant />
    </setBody>
    <to uri="http://localhost:9090/file?httpMethod=GET"/>
```

Exception :

```
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
Retrying request
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
Retrying request
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
Retrying request
```

If I remove everything from header then service call is successful but I cant loose the data in the header. I need this data at the end of the route.

Comment: If a HTTP call without header is working, probably [enricher](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/enrich-eip.html) will help

Comment: you can also keep the data you need in the exchange properties, and not in the headers. Instead of setHeader, just do a setProperty.

Comment: Thanks Snehar, using properties worked, but I am still not sure why do we need to remove all header information for calling a GET service.

Comment: can you add `bridgeEndpoint=true' to your http request and try with the headers?